# Is it possible to get a Google voice number without already having a phone number?

Tags: google-voice

I currently have no phone number; I can make outgoing calls via the widget in gmail, but I cannot receive calls (as far as I know). I know that you can set up a google voice number to forward to Google chat, and this is exactly what I want. The problem is, I can't get a Google voice number in the first place, because it first requires that I have an existing phone number, even if I wouldn't use it.

So, it is possible to skip providing an existing phone number, and just get a google voice number that forwards to Google chat?

Alternatively, is there any free phone service that can be used without a phone and lets you receive calls from any number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IPKall](http://www.ipkall.com/)  gives you phone number that can be forwarded to a VOIP provider and can be used to receive calls using SIP software. You don't pay for the number and you can get a free VOIP account from some providers, check the IPKall website for examples.

[Sipgate One](http://www.sipgate.com/one) gives you a phone number that can receive calls and you can register SIP client with their servers. You get the number for free, however Sipgate One is out of stock for quite some time.

Comment: Thank you, but I've having some problems getting this to work. I installed X-Lite, registered it with callcentric, and successfully called the test number. Then I successfully created a IPKall number. However, when I dialed the IPKall number from gmail, it rang twice then played a message saying it could not connect due to network error 101. I don't even know what step of the way the error is coming from.

Comment: Try calling the IPKall number from another number (preferably real PSTN phone number) to see if the number is active indeed. Check if you see anything in the Callcentric calls.

Comment: I tried calling it from two different online calling services, and neither of them made it ring. Callcentric.com shows no received calls (it does show the calls I made).

Comment: Ok, I also tried it from a real (international) phone, and it didn't work then either (also, still no call received log at callcentric).

Comment: Did you forward your DID to the correct SIP address (sip username: 1777.....; sip hostname:in.callcentric.com)? If so and it still doesn't work, try the IPKall support forum at voxilla: http://forum.voxilla.com/forums/ipkall-support-forum.37/

Comment: I think so - SIP is checked, it's the right 1777 number, and the hostname is "callcentric.com". I'll try the forum, but I've got one question first - does this require that the router serving my computer be configured to accept inbound requests? Because I'm doing this from various free wifi locations, and I'm sure they filter like crazy.

Comment: I think that the hostname should be in.callcentric.com, not just callcentric.com. As for the router -- not necessarily, if the SIP softphone is registered you should be able to receive calls. But if the incoming calls are not registered on the Callcentric site, it means that they are not even forwarded from IPKall to Callcentric, I think that the missing `in.` in the hostname is the issue. But I think that you are going through too much hops for this. There are VOIP providers (incl Callcentric) that sell incoming numbers (DIDs) for a couple of dollars, and you won't have to do any forwarding.

Comment: It works now, thank you - it was the hostname that was the issue, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Bypass Google Voice when adding phone number for verification (at step 3 & 4).

Login with your Gmail account to begin register for Google Voice account → Choose a US Phone Number → Continue → Choose PIN → Continue.

Now you will be asked to add a real phone number in US to verify Google Voice account, just edit your current URL to this URL: https://www.google.com/voice/?setup=finishthen

You've already finished registering a basic US phone number with Google Voice without verifying or adding anything.

Note: your Google Voice is still not actives any function, so you can not click, edit or do anything in Google Voice.

Back to gmail.com with your Google Voice account and Login → *Setting* → *Labs* → and enable these applications:

- Google Voice player in mail
- SMS in Chat gadget
- Text Messaging (SMS) in Chat

Comment: Old answer. Didn't work in 2019.

Answer (score 1):

I am a paid user of Google Voice and ported my Verizon phone number to Google, I think they got $10 out of this tight wad above and beyond the fee to port the number-- not sure anymore it was a while ago. The whole operation wasn't really that expensive.

Anyway, it is just that we haven't gotten my son a bona fide phone to port a number from any carrier and there really isn't any need. I couldn't use my number as a forwarding number because it is already Google Voice number. But he has a local Google Voice number now. Below is what I did to verify a forwarding number.

There is a service called "Burner - Disposable Numbers" by Ad Hoc Labs, Inc. I used their Android app to generate a temporary number. I used that temporary number as the forwarding number. Then I just deleted the forwarding number once the Google Voice number was issued. I still can't make calls in or out from my son's tablet. But, I'm close.

This probably violates half of the terms of service or more (I just checked the box, I didn't really read them), but I'm hoping the Google overlords let it slide as we are good Internet users that are happy with their services and are helping them 'hook' the next generation.